# jquery to submit form only after condition is valid and display alert if not

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this jQuery code. I want to find out what is causing the `alertify.error()` to displayed as many times as it executes foreach loop to find the sum of the value of text box. Can somebody help me here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sum = claculateTotal();
    if ($("#TotalWeigh").val() != sum) {
      alertify.error('Total weigh should be equal to the sum of weigh of all leaf quality.');
      return false;
    } else {
      this.submit();
    }
  });

  function claculateTotal() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.leafWeigh').each(function() {
      sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    return sum;
  }
});
```

And i have my html code for text boxes as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.boughtWeighingModel.Count(); i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.boughtWeighingModel[i].LeafQaualityWeight, 
         new { @class = "form-control leafWeigh" })
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: It's being shown as `valid` is `false`. If you need further help than that, then we'd need to see your HTML. A working snippet wouldn't go amiss either

Comment: $("#TotalWeigh").val() is not equal to sum

Comment: @Pradip Shrestha, Is it possible that any other event is triggering form submit?

Comment: Acutally the problem here is the alert message is displayed as many time as the foreach is executed beside this all work fine.  If there are three leafWeigh textboxes it display there alert message if the condition is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you really need a `<form>` element?

HTML

```
<input name="" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
submit.onclick = function(){
   // validate and do some ajax...
}
```